# Using Tabulator in Angular 8 all data and headers show in the first column

Tags: angular, tabulator

In Angular 8, I have set up a tabulator-table component (Tabulator) and I am trying to send data from the app.component to the tabulator-table.  I am passing the data between the two components using a shared service.  The data is being transferred successfully however when I attempt a drawTable() command, I am having an issue where all of the headers and row data are shown in the first column of the Tabulator grid.  I have worked on this over the past day and a half so any assistance would be gretly appreciated.

**data-table.service.ts**
`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataTableService {

  arrayData:any[];
  columnData:any[];

  constructor() { }
}
```

`

**appComponent.html**

```
`
<app-tabulator-table></app-tabulator-table>
`
```

**appComponent.ts**

```
`
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataTableService } from './services/data-table.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'StoresAppUI';

  myTableData: any[] = this.getData()
  myColumnNames: any[] = this.getColumns();
  height: string = '311px';

  get arrayData():any[] {
    return this.dataService.arrayData;
  }

  set arrayData(value : any[]) {
    this.dataService.arrayData = value;
  }

  get columnData():any[] {
    return this.dataService.columnData;
  }

  set columnData(value: any[]) {
    this.dataService.columnData = value;
  }

  constructor(private dataService: DataTableService) {}

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.dataService.arrayData = this.getData();
    console.log('myTableData => ', this.dataService.arrayData);

    this.dataService.columnData = this.getColumns();
    console.log('myColumnNames = ', this.dataService.columnData);
  }


  getData(): any[]
  {
    let data:any[] = [
      {firstname: "Al", lastname:"Alberts", age:66},
      {firstname: "Bob", lastname:"Banes", age:66},
      {firstname: "Chuck", lastname:"Chandler", age:55},
      {firstname: "Donnie", lastname:"Darwin", age:77},
    ]
    return  data;
  }

  getColumns():any[]
  {
    let cols: any[] = [
      {title: 'First', field:'firstname', width:100},
      {title: 'Last', field: 'lastname', width:100},
      {title: 'Age', field: 'age', width:100}
    ];
    return cols;
  }
}
`
```

**tabulator-table.component.html**

```
`
<div id="my-tabular-table"></div>
`
```

**tabulator-table.component.ts**

```
`
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";
import { DataTableService } from "../../services/data-table.service";

/**
 * This is a wrapper class for the tabulator JS library.
 * For more info see http://tabulator.info
 */
@Component({
  selector: "app-tabulator-table",
  templateUrl: "./tabulator-table.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./tabulator-table.component.css"],
})
export class TabulatorTableComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {
  @Input() tableData: any[];
  @Input() columns: any[];
  @Input() height: string = "311px";

  get arrayData(): any[] {
    return this.dataService.arrayData;
  }

  get columnData(): any[] {
    return this.dataService.columnData;
  }

  tab = document.createElement("div");

  constructor(private dataService: DataTableService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableData = this.dataService.arrayData;
    console.log("tableData (in table) => ", this.tableData);

    this.columns = this.dataService.columnData;
    console.log("columns (in table) => ", this.columns);

    this.drawTable();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.drawTable();
  }

  private drawTable(): void {
    new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      data: this.tableData,
      reactiveData: true, //enable data reactivity
      columns: this.columns,
      layout: "fitColumns",
      width: "600px",
      height: "311px",
    });
    document.getElementById("my-tabular-table").appendChild(this.tab);
  }
}
`
```

Here is results after showing columns and data being passed to the drawTable() function per Marc's request.

**columns

[
    {
        "title": "First",
        "field": "firstname",
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "title": "Last",
        "field": "lastname",
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "title": "Age",
        "field": "age",
        "width": 100
    }
]
data
[
    {
        "firstname": "Al",
        "lastname": "Alberts",
        "age": 66
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Banes",
        "age": 66
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Chuck",
        "lastname": "Chandler",
        "age": 55
    },
    {
        "firstname": "Donnie",
        "lastname": "Dreary",
        "age": 77
    }
]**

***After following Oli's post, I realized I needed to move the tabulator.css code into the styles.css at the root of the project.  After that, all  data is appearing correctly in the table.***

Thanks all for the rapid responses.

Comment: Please make a console.info  for this.columns and this.tableData in drawTable function.   console.info(JSON.stringify(this.tableData, null, 4));

Comment: Your code is like this: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1509   .  Thats good. So first step is to debug data in drawTable.

Answer (score 0):

In your tabulator class add encapsulation property

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabulator-table',
  templateUrl: './tabulator-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabulator-table.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```